What are these black drainage pipes in my basement and can I move them?
I'm thinking of finishing my Ontario basement but would first like to understand more about some of the black drainage pipes.


The builder installed rough-ins for a bathroom, with an orientation that they outlined in orange, but I'm having trouble understanding what each pipe is for. I also can't imagine any arrangement of sink, toilet and bath that could fit where the pipes are. Is it normal to have to move these a few feet?



Further down, I have these two pipes. The one in the background is fed by drainage pipes from the kitchen sink and an upstairs bathroom, so I know what it's for, but the foot of the pipe awkwardly juts out. Is it possible to replace the bottom part of the piping so the whole assembly is straight? It would allow me to hide it in the framing instead of having to build out a bulkhead.

In the foreground (marked in orange), what is the stump for? It protrudes about 15" from the concrete so if I were to develop the space would I have to build a bulkhead for that going all the way up to the ceiling? Or would it be possible to push this to be flush with the wall as in (2)?



if they are already cast in concrete you will have a pretty hard time moving them. Do you have any plans that include what appliances will be where?

The pipes are for : sink/ vanity (red),  Toilet (blue),  Shower or tub/shower (yellow).
Noting the distance from existing walls would help determining a layout. generally a tub or shower would go against a wall, but there can be alternate layouts.
The stump in the foreground of the 2nd pic is most likely for a toilet.
Moving can be done, but would involve cutting out the concrete. You will need to determine if it is worth it to you to have that done. You may take measurements and note them on a sketch of your basement and take pics to a draftsman to help draw a usable plan that is suitable to you without moving the pipes. They were put in place according to a plan that was drawn, so should be usable in their current location.  Finding the blueprints for your home would solve the problem.


Yes it is normal to have to change the pipes especially if you are at all particular with a bathroom layout.  Did you not get some kind of plan that shows what the bathroom could look like?  You'd definitely need a p-trap for a shower or a bathtub which requires jack hammering around the tub/shower rough in.
The pipes are offset from the wall as your foundation footing projects into the underground space and your horizontal sewer service line runs next to the footing.  Ideally you handle this area by having an interior wall division that is perpendicular to the outside wall and helps to hide the riser.  You just make that wall a little wider than normal.
I don't know what #3 is.  It could be a clean out for perimeter drain.  It could be a passive depressurization point for radon mitigation.  It could be connected to the sewer.  You can jackhammer around it and install a cleanout cap that is flush to the finished floor.  They make caps with recessed heads for removal.
The alternate solutions around the bulkhead are really expensive at this point.  You could bring the sewer service line above the slab and hide it in the framing of the exterior wall.  You could hide it in a ceiling bulk head that runs along an interior dividing wall that you align your closets with.  You could change the sewer service line to exit the house at that wall and have it run along the exterior of your house underground.  I've done these solutions but only when I was already replacing the slab, re-digging the outside of the house or already had aerial sewer service line that couldn't easily be hidden.
It comes down to how valuable the space is and how much money it is worth to you.
The larger issue for you is how to hide your hvac air ducts.

In my area, P-traps are installed and under the slab for tubs and showers. No need to jackhammer to put them in.

Interesting.  In my area they typically box out this section of the slab to allow adjustment for shower/tub position.  If the p-trap is already in the slab ( it could be ) then as long as you are happy with the position of the shower/tub drain no need to jack hammer.

I assume Canada will be similar, just times 2.5 for everything in cm.
PVC drain pipes come in a variety of sizes, including:
1.5 in: Used for kitchen sinks, bathroom vanities, and tubs
1.5-2 in: Used for washing machines, showers, and bathtubs
3-4 in: Used for toilets
So I'm pretty sure you could map up your sizes to the expected uses.
For your bottom photo, the bottom is another stub into the drain lines.  The top one gives you a cleanup port that isn't in the wall.  Certainly you could have this all in the wall, though at this point that would require cutting the slab and re-routing.

-1 Google AI gives me the following You've been around long enough that you should know better.

Nothing wrong with using Google to find authoritative answers, but Google AI makes stuff up. It's a guess at best, and we're looking for something more trustworthy here. If you can find a human-written page  which states this, that would be a better citation.
